# How to get a list of users around me, except several specific users, in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: database, firebase, database-design, google-cloud-firestore

When my app is opening, I get 10 users among 10.000 users which are around my position, so it costs me 10 reads in Cloud Firestore.

How, in my second opening of my app, get 10 users among 10.000 which are around my position, ***without*** the 10 first ones that I have already seen ?

- I have no problem to get the 10.000 users around my position, my problem is only about the exclusion
- The 10.000 users around me are not in order and are not the same at different opening of my app because of location, so I can't use pagination
- My third opening will have to exclude the 20 users already seen and then exclude 30 and so on.
- I can't filter in local because it will cost me too many reads in for example the use case when I have 10.000 users around me and 5000 that I have already seen

---

Is there any way to do that in Cloud Firestore or do I have to change ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore doesn't provide any way to *exclude* specific results from a query.  The only thing you can do is *include* documents that match your criteria.  If you're not able to use a where clause to filter for the documents that should match, then what you're trying to do isn't possible - you are always going to have to pay the cost of the documents already seen (by whatever criteria you determine that a document is seen).

Comment: I just saw the official documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any. Is it now possible to fulfill my request using the "not-in" operator?